# How do I set the value for field_stock?

Tags: 8, commerce

I use module commerce_stock on Drupal 8.

I get back product data and I create a product with its data. I have to create a field field_stock (Stock level) in variations, which I create with the following code.

```
$variation =  ProductVariation::create(['type' => 'default', 'sku' => 'sku1', 'status' => TRUE, 'price' => $price]);
```

How do I add the value to field_stock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to add the value to field_stock (Stock level).

```
$variation =  ProductVariation::create(['type' => 'default', 'sku' => $json['22107'], 'status' => TRUE, 'price' => $price]);
$variation->save();
//Stock
$stock = ['stock' => ['value' => 100]];
$var = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('commerce_product_variation')->load($variation->id());
$var->set('field_stock', [$stock]);
$var->save();
```

My field_stock in database is empty but this code create a commerce_stock_transaction in database with my quantity.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that field_stock is a field on your ProductVariation, I believe you should be able to set the field value like so:

```
$variation =  ProductVariation::create(['type' => 'default', 'sku' => 
   'sku1', 'status' => TRUE, 'price' => $price]);

$variation->set('field_stock', "100"); // or w/e value or logic here
$variation->save();
```

Comment: Yes i have test this code but it doesn't work. It return no error and when i check in database, field_stock is empty.

Comment: @Romest did you find any solution of this? i also tried all above and not worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

From Commerce Stock 2, you have to adjust the stock level with transactions. So you can create an transaction in StockServiceManager:

```
public function createTransaction(PurchasableEntityInterface $entity, $location_id, $zone, $quantity, $unit_cost, $currency_code, $transaction_type_id, array $metadata = []);
```

So adding 1 to the stock level could look like:

```
$stockManager = Drupal::service('commerce_stock.service_manager');
$stockManager->createTransaction($entity, 1, '', 1, null, null, StockTransactionsInterface::STOCK_IN);
```